# To increase Hosted Apple on-demand resources size beyond 20GB for iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-application, on-demand-resources

Apple has set the maximum capacity of on-demand resources for an app at 20GB. We are on the verge of exceeding that boundary.
What is the solution if we need to add extra resources that exceed the 20GB limit?

Because of this limitation, we have been unable to introduce additional features.